# how to add two variables in .html() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two variables in ajax's success, how to add this in .html() attribute.

```
    $("#select_name").html();//"data.str & data.re are the variables
```

Comment: show your homework, what you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate it:

```
$("#select_name").html(data.str+data.re);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go through jquery API for `html()` & `html(string)` first to try something.

[Here is the link for jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

It should be like

`$("#id<Selector>").html("<Your input strings>");`

If you want to fetch `innerHTML` of a tag, then above code without input string should be used. 
`$("#id<Selector>").html();`

In your case, this should be like

`$("#select_name").html("First variable = "+data.str+"  second variable="+data.re);`